# bat to convert csv format with all merged lines saved by Kantu Selenium Ide need conversion in a csv with all separated lines

Tags: selenium, csv, batch-file, format, kantu

I use Kantu Seleniun Ide to extract from webpages and save data in csv.

Kantu Seleniun Ide save all data extracted in csv with all lines merged, I need a classic format of csv with all lines separated.

I need a bat file to convert these csv with all merged lines in classic csv with separated lines for windows 7.

Csv saved by Kantu Seleniun Ide
[image: csv with merged lines]

Csv in classic format with separated lines
[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how either of the files you've shown in your images, _(you should have posted the content directly though)_, are CSV's? I would suggest that your lines are not being output merged at all but they're simply being viewed in the wrong program, `notepad.exe`. The problem is most likely that your program outputs the CSV using Unix or Mac, LF or CR line endings instead of Windows CRLF. If your file is using Unix LF, endings, _(most likely)_, then you could fix that by using, `Find /V ""<"test.csv">"converted.csv"`, then open `converted.csv` in Windows notepad to verify.

Comment: The question is too broad, you posted images of your files, so we cannot access the data, you also did not show any attempts of your own?

Comment: Hi the images is the exact csv saved from Kantu here the info of command "https://ui.vision/kantu/docs/selenium-ide/csvsave" Kantu save all data in csv with 1 line. I use windows 7 and open the csv with notepad. The default csv of Kantu have separated lines but when you extract from website and save in csv save merged all lines in csv like the picture i add. Kantu save merged lines in ANSI and UTF-8 csv format. I need csv with separated lines. Thanks to all

Comment: @Compo Your solution working like a charm, converted csv have separated lines, if you post this solution I accept it, it's the solution to my problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that your lines are not being output merged at all but they're simply being viewed in the wrong program, `notepad.exe`.

The problem is most likely that your program outputs the CSV using Unix or Mac, `LF` or `CR` line endings instead of Windows `CRLF`.

If your file is using Unix `LF`, endings, *(most likely)*, then you could fix that by using:

```bat
Find /V ""<"test.csv">"converted.csv"
```

*Then open `converted.csv` in Windows notepad to verify the conversion.*